# Facebook insights API now 4 days old

Tags: json, facebook-insights

I have a number of pages where I download insights via the Graph API. The stats stopped updating around the 25th of November across all pages. It is now the 29th and only admin stats are available using the since= parameter.

I am also verifying this independently via the Explorer page (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

I know the generally accepted delay is 48 hours. Is there something I can do to get the latest data?